# Create folder from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension where I am trying to create a folder from extension to save some of the files. I believe there are some security constraints for this but I am not sure if this can be done if yes could someone please guide me how to do this? I have tried FileSystem APIs but I was not able to physically see where the file was created and access it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [html5rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) gives an overview of how to create all of this.

This is how you create a directory

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
  fs.root.getDirectory('MyPictures', {create: true}, function(dirEntry) {
    ...
  }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes I saw that article but where is this file created? Can I access them physically? I wanted to create a folder from my extension and save some files in it and then I have to physically copy those files to different location. I am using windows 7.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That's not at all what the title of the question asked. It is not a real file system. You can't browse to it.

Comment: @isiva did you get what you wanted as I am after the same thing!